# Iterating over a string containing special characters with Dart

Tags: string, dart

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve a corresponding sprite in a game for each character of a string; but when creating a String like so:

```
var s = "²";
```

The  resulting String in the debugger or when printed is "Â²" and its length is 2.
I've also looked at the string runes and there is 2 of them.

So I don't get how I'm supposed to iterate over a string containing special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Dart Editor saves files as UTF8 without BOM by default and it's causing weird characters happening on my Windows machine only if meta meta charset="utf-8" is not in head.

Converting files to UTF8 **with** BOM using Notepad++ or adding meta charset="utf-8", solved the problem and everything is compiling nicely to JS.

Comment: What Dart version are you using? As far as I remember there was a DartEditor bug related to UTF-8 but I think that is fixed.

Comment: Yeah I saw that in the issue tracker but it was fixed a while ago. I'm using Dart Editor version 1.3.0.dev_07_10 (DEV)

Comment: Just updated to Dart Editor version 1.3.0.dev_07_12 (DEV) same issue

Comment: I think you should file another bug.

Comment: It seems that I can't reproduce it, I only have one project affected, I don't get it.

Comment: I guess this is because you created the file while DartEditor still had the bug.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the behaviour is depending of either the dart or HTML file encoding: when encoded UTF8 without BOM (default) and without meta charset in the HTML the dart file is not parsed correctly. But the compiled JS is anyway.

Comment: opened an issue over here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18150 OMG forgot to title the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```dart
s.codeUnits.forEach((e) => print(new String.fromCharCode(e)));
```

Comment: `"²".codeUnits.forEach((e) => print(new String.fromCharCode(e)));` prints Â then ². also s.codeUnits.length is 2 :/

Comment: Actually I don't get the same results on try.dartlang.org, I guess something must be wrong with my project inside Dart Editor

Comment: Maybe an OS specific issue?

Comment: Yep it seems that Windows does not like UTF8 without BOM.